# How to use balanced binary trees to solve this challenge?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

```
       1(70)
        / \
       /   \
    2(40)  5(10)
     / \      \
    /   \      \
 3(60)  4(80)  6(20)
         / \
        /   \
     7(30)  8(50)
```

This is for an online challenge (not live contest). I don't need someone to solve for me, just to push in right direction. Trying to learn.

Each node has a unique ID, no two people have same salary. Person #1 has salary $70, person #7 has $30 salary, for example. Tree structure denotes who supervises who. Question is who has kth lowest salary on a person's subordinates.

For example I choose person #2. Who is 2nd lowest among subordinates? #2's subordinates are 3, 4, 7, 8. 2nd lowest salary is $50 belonging to person #8.

There are many queries so structure to must be efficient.

I thought about this problem and researched data structures. Binary tree seems like a good idea but I need help.

For example I think ideal structure look like, for person #2:

```
    2(40)  
     / \      
    /   \      
 7(30)  3(60)
         / \
        /   \
     8(50)  4(80)
```

Every child node is subordinate of #2, every left branch has lower salary than on right. If I store how many children at each node I can get kth lowest.

For example: From #2, left branch 1 node, right branch 3 nodes. So 2nd lowest - 1 means I now want 1st lowest in right branch.

Move to #3, 1st lowest points to #8 with $50 which is correct.

My question:

1. Is this approach as I describe it a good one? Is it a valid approach?
2. I am having trouble figuring out how to construct this kind of tree. I think I can make them recursively. But hard to figure out how to make all children into new tree sorted by salary. Need some light help.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you mess up the dependency structure.  For example, In your tree rooted at `2`, if I then queried for something about `4`, your tree says `4` has no children, which is false- `7` and `8` should be children of `4`.

Comment: Not in terms of salary ordering. That is what the second tree is meant to show. Second tree purely just arrangement of salary orderings among all descendents of root, in BST format. If query on 4, tree would be different. Or am I talking crazy

Comment: My point is that in your solution, you would need to construct a new binary search tree each time you make a query.  e.g. how would you use the tree you posted rooted at `2` to query for the 1st lowest salary for `4`?  This does not seem efficient enough,

Comment: Yes, each person would have their own binary search tree, created from merging the search trees of children.

Comment: The problem is that the children of the nodes in the original tree does not correspond to the children of the nodes in the binary search tree.  I do not see an efficient way to compute the binary trees other than recomputing it from scratch on each query.  If the number of queries >> number of nodes, you can compute a tree for each node and store it, and you will have complexity O(q *log(n)), but I don't think this is the case for you?

Comment: Is the tree constant or changing over time?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses O(n log^2 n + q log n) time and O(n log^2 n) space (not the best on the latter count, but probably good enough given the limits).

Implement a *purely functional* sorted list (as an augmented binary search tree) with the following operations and some way to iterate.

```
EmptyList() -> returns the empty list
Insert(list, key) -> returns the list where |key| has been inserted into |list|
Length(list) -> returns the length of the list
Get(list, k) -> returns the element at index |k| in |list|
```

On top of these operations, implement an operation

```
Merge(list1, list2) -> returns the union of |list1| and |list2|
```

by inserting the elements of the shorter list into the longer.

Now do the obvious thing: traverse the employee hierarchy from leaves to root, setting the ordered list for each employee to the appropriate merge of her subordinate lists, and answer the queries.

#### Analysis (sketch)

Each query takes O(log n) time. The interesting part of the analysis pertains to the preprocessing.

The cost of preprocessing is dominated by the cost of calling `Insert()`, specifically from `Merge()`, since there are n other insertions. Each insertion takes O(log n) time and costs O(log n) space (measuring in words).

What keeps the preprocessing from being quadratic is an implicit [heavy path decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_path_decomposition). Every time we merge two lists, neither list is merged subsequently. Since the shorter list is inserted into the longer, every time a key is inserted into a list, that list is at least twice as long as the list into which that key was previously inserted. It follows that each key is the subject of at most lg n insertions, which suffices to establish a bound of O(n log n) insertions overall and thus the claimed resource bounds.

Comment: The problem is merging subordinate lists can lead to O(n^2) space, not O(n log^2 n) (imagine a tree that is linear, person 1 head of person 2, who is head of person 3, ..., head of person n)

Comment: @user5053260 It would be quadratic space except for the fact that the BSTs backing the sorted lists are sharing a lot of subtrees.

Comment: I am not sure this answer helps, I already know that solution needs some kind of merge operation recursively, hard part is structuring preprocessing and not going into high memory (while also answering queries quickly)

Comment: @user5053260 I guess I didn't make myself clear. The secret sauce here is a merge operation whose incremental space requirement is proportional to the length of the *shorter input* (not the merged list) together with heavy path.

Comment: Is your approach drastically different from what I described in the original post somewhere? I am failing to understand how it is improvement

Comment: I think my #1 difficulty is understanding what is actually being stored for a node. Ideally, in a perfect world, query time is O(1) if each employee has sorted list of salaries of subordinates. But making this is O(n^2) memory and time I think. So somehow query lookup should be log(n) instead but i don't know what this would be "searching on." Need some way to give ordered structure to salaries but within subordinates only, and finding all subordinates requires recursing into each child from the person targeted. When recursing into subordinates, perform merge.

Comment: @user5053260 We end up with one sorted list per employee. It's not quadratic because these sorted lists share a lot of internal structure. There's no algorithmic difference here; the difference is in the data structures.

Comment: How can you have a sorted list per employee but also have non-quadratic space? Feels like a contradiction to me. When you say each employee has a sorted list are you actually mean something else?

Comment: @user5053260 There's no arguing with your feelings, apparently. Good luck.

Comment: There is no need to be rude. I merely ask clarification because what you are saying seems like it self-contradicts unless you are meaning something else by "ordered list." An ordered list is an object of n items. If person k has (k-1) subordinates, sum k from 1 to n is n(n+1)/2, O(n^2) space.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat (this is a different user with a similar name): Could you explain how you get the O(n * log^2(n)) ? IIRC, the root will point to a list of n elements. The immediate two children will have n-k and (k-1) elements of the above list (excluding the root) which leads to n-1, if we assume that the list at root can be split into two separate sub-lists. This assumption is true for BST but not for the example above.
If the assumption holds. the next level will similarly have n - 2^0 - 2^1. If we maintain these separately the summation will be O(n*lg(n)) as per my calculations.

Comment: @user1952500 It's O(n log n) insertions, each requiring time O(log n). The worst case here is a hierarchy that is a complete binary tree, where each of lg n levels requires Theta(n) insertions.

Comment: @user1952500 Each insertion takes O(log n) words of memory for the functional data structure that I have in mind.

Comment: @user1952500 I think the main confusion here is with the data structure. There is a classic book about this, called "Purely functional data structures" by Chris Okasaki, for example available as a PDF here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf Short version: you can achieve logarithmic time operations in balanced binary search trees by path copying, i.e. only regenerating the O(log n) nodes that are actually modified in an insert operation and sharing the remaining structure with the old version of the DS

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.  For each node, we will construct an array of all children's values of that node and keep this in sorted order.  The result we are looking for is a dictionary of the form

```
{ 1 : [10, 20, 30, 40, 60 80],
  2 : [30, 50, 60, 80] 
  ...
}
```

Once we have this, to query for any node for the ith lowest salary, just take the ith element of the array.  The total time to do all the queries is O( q ) where q is the number of queries.

How do we construct this?  Assuming you have a pointer to the root node, you can recursively construct the sorted salaries for each child.  Store those values in the result.  Make a copy of each child's array, and insert each child's salary into the child's copied array.  Use binary search to find the position, since each array is sorted.  Now you have k sorted arrays, you merge them to get a sorted array.  If you are merging two arrays, this can be done in linear time.  Simply loop, picking the first element of the array that is smaller each time.

For the case where each node has 2 children, merging the two children's arrays is O(n) tine.  Inserting the salaries of each node to its corresponding array is O(log(n)) per node since we use binary search.  Copying the children array is O(n), and there are n nodes, so we have O(n^2) total time for pre-processing.

Total run time is O(n^2 + q)

What if we can not assume each node has at most 2 children?  Then to merge the arrays, use [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/) algorithm.  This runs in O(nlog(k)) where k is the number of arrays to merge, since we pop from the heap once per element, and resizing the heap takes O(log(k)) when there are k arrays.  `k<=n` so we can simplify this to O(nlog(n)).  So the total running time is unchanged.

The space complexity of this solution is O(n^2).

Comment: good solution, but complexity is not O(log n) , its O(1) per query, since finding kth lowest in sorted array is a simple O(1) direct element access, and doesnt require binary search.

Comment: This could lead to O(n^2) space complexity if the tree is unbalanced.

Comment: @user1952500 yes, this is not space efficient.  I think there may be a better solution that doesn't require keeping repeated copies of the arrays.

Comment: @James I believe it is possible for a person to have multiple children, but each person has at most one parent (except for the main boss / head node)

Comment: Also what about if we have a very linear tree? Person 1 head of person 2 head of person 3 head of person 4... this would need a lot of space

Comment: @user5053260 thats exactly the case where we need O(n^2) space.

Comment: That would need many GB so I think there is a better way. I'll think on this a little

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. You can't have Omega(n^2) space complexity and still O(n log n) construction time. Your algorithm needs Omega(n^2) time.

Comment: @NiklasB. thanks for pointing that out!  I forgot the O(n) per node time requirement to copy the children arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The question has two parts: first, finding the specified person, and then finding the kth subordinate.
Since the tree is not ordered by id, to find the specified perspn by id requires walking the whole tree until the specified id is found. To speed up this part, we can builda hash map that would allow us to find the person node by id in O(1) time and require O(n) space and set-up time.
Then, to find the subordinate with the kth lowest salary, we need to search the subtree. Since its not ordered by salary, we would have to scan the whole subtree and find the kth lowest salary. This could be done using an array or a heap (putting the subtree nodes into array or heap). This second part would O(m log k) time using the heap to keep the lowest k items, where m is the number of sub-ordinates, and require O(k) space. This should be acceptable if m (number of subordinates of specified person), and k are small.